# Enviar dados via comunicação serial Arduino - Raspberry

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

Bom dia, estou tendo problemas ao receber os dados que o Arduino está enviando, o que pretendo é ler as informações da linha, jogar estas informações em uma variável e comparar os valores no Raspberry. O problema é que como quero separar as informações por linha, tenho que usar o comando no arduino Serial.println, que no Raspberry gera, além do número/texto desejado, os caracteres de pular linha "\r\n", gerando conflito na minha comparação no rasp. Como posso separar estas informações sem gerar estes caracteres?

Código no arduino:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println("1");
delay(500);
Serial.println("2");
delay(500);
Serial.println("11");
delay(500);
}
```

Código no Raspberry:

```
import serial
comunicacaoSerial=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
k=str()

while 1:
      k=comunicacaoSerial.read()
      int_k = int(k)
      print(k==1)
```

Comment: Tentou dar um `.split('\n')` na sua variável 'k'?

    ```k = k.split('\n')[0]```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode tratar esse `\n` no seu código do raspberry, com `split()` na variável `k`, ou tente usar:

```
k=comunicacaoSerial.readlines()
```

ao inves de

```
k=comunicacaoSerial.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá

O método `.read()` não é o mais indicado neste cenário, pois ele assume o valor de 1 byte por padrão e isto pode fazer com que você leia apenas uma parte do buffer. Neste caso é recomendável utilizar o `.readline()`, porém para que este funcione adequadamente você deve definir o timeout de leitura ou a aplicação ficará aguardando eternamente o "\n", para isto você deve passar o valor do timeout de leitura ao instanciar a classe Serial. Exemplo:

```py
# Timeout de 2 segundos
my_serial = Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, timeout=2)
```

Para mais infos olhe neste [link](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#readline)